# Doing a matrix with absolute frequencies

Tags: r, matrix, replication

I have two matrices:
Matrix 1, a vector with :

```
matrix(c(0.16, 0.24, 0.16, 0.08, 0.09, 0.12, 0.06, 0.04, 0.04, 0.01))
```

Actually, I created it using the function "FOR", utilizing a Punnett square with the frequencies 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1.

And second, I have the matrix 2:

```
                [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]      [,8]      [,9]      [,10]    
      [1,] "A 1 A 1" "B 1 B 1" "C 1 C 1" "D 1 D 1" "E 1 E 1" "F 1 F 1" "G 1 G 1" "H 1 H 1" "I 1 I 1" "J 1 J 1"
      [2,] "A 1 A 2" "B 1 B 2" "C 1 C 2" "D 1 D 2" "E 1 E 2" "F 1 F 2" "G 1 G 2" "H 1 H 2" "I 1 I 2" "J 1 J 2"
      [3,] "A 1 A 3" "B 1 B 3" "C 1 C 3" "D 1 D 3" "E 1 E 3" "F 1 F 3" "G 1 G 3" "H 1 H 3" "I 1 I 3" "J 1 J 3"
      [4,] "A 1 A 4" "B 1 B 4" "C 1 C 4" "D 1 D 4" "E 1 E 4" "F 1 F 4" "G 1 G 4" "H 1 H 4" "I 1 I 4" "J 1 J 4"
      [5,] "A 2 A 2" "B 2 B 2" "C 2 C 2" "D 2 D 2" "E 2 E 2" "F 2 F 2" "G 2 G 2" "H 2 H 2" "I 2 I 2" "J 2 J 2"
      [6,] "A 2 A 3" "B 2 B 3" "C 2 C 3" "D 2 D 3" "E 2 E 3" "F 2 F 3" "G 2 G 3" "H 2 H 3" "I 2 I 3" "J 2 J 3"
      [7,] "A 2 A 4" "B 2 B 4" "C 2 C 4" "D 2 D 4" "E 2 E 4" "F 2 F 4" "G 2 G 4" "H 2 H 4" "I 2 I 4" "J 2 J 4"
      [8,] "A 3 A 3" "B 3 B 3" "C 3 C 3" "D 3 D 3" "E 3 E 3" "F 3 F 3" "G 3 G 3" "H 3 H 3" "I 3 I 3" "J 3 J 3"
      [9,] "A 3 A 4" "B 3 B 4" "C 3 C 4" "D 3 D 4" "E 3 E 4" "F 3 F 4" "G 3 G 4" "H 3 H 4" "I 3 I 4" "J 3 J 4"
     [10,] "A 4 A 4" "B 4 B 4" "C 4 C 4" "D 4 D 4" "E 4 E 4" "F 4 F 4" "G 4 G 4" "H 4 H 4" "I 4 I 4" "J 4 J 4"
```

I want a new table (lines=100, columns=10) with each column of matrix 2, having the frequencies of matrix 1. So I will have 16 times "A1A1", 24 times "A1A2" and so on. The same for the others columns.
But I want to do this for any frequencies (matrix 1) and for any number of columns lines of matrix 2.

Comment: JAL, I'm also trying the function "FOR":
pop.mae<-matrix(0, 100, num.locos)
for(i in 1:nrow(genotipos2))
for(j in 1:ncol(genotipos2))
{
pop.mae[,j]<-(t(t((rep(matrix2[i,j], times=((matrix1[i])*100))))))
}

Where "pop.mae" it is a matrix that receive the results, but I don't get the point, I couldn't think in a way to do this, actually, i know that my script doesn't make sense.

Comment: Use `rep` function combined with `apply`, where apply is done column wise. You need to convert that frequency vector to an integer vector that sums to 100 (desired number of columns in output matrix)

Comment: Pafnucy, I'm feeling that I'm stupid, jeje..Actually I already used the function apply in other case, but I couldn't imagine how to "mix" these matrices and do one with 100 lines and 10 columns with the data in matrix 2 using the function apply, If I'm not asking for too much, could you help me to do this? Thank you very much JAL and Pafnucy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
 out <- matrix(rep(c(m2),m1[row(m2)]*100),100,10)
 dim(out)
 #[1] 100  10
```

#### data

```
m1 <- matrix(c(0.16, 0.24, 0.16, 0.08, 0.09, 0.12, 0.06, 0.04, 0.04, 0.01))

m2 <-  structure(c("A 1 A 1", "A 1 A 2", "A 1 A 3", "A 1 A 4", "A 2 A 2", 
"A 2 A 3", "A 2 A 4", "A 3 A 3", "A 3 A 4", "A 4 A 4", "B 1 B 1", 
"B 1 B 2", "B 1 B 3", "B 1 B 4", "B 2 B 2", "B 2 B 3", "B 2 B 4", 
"B 3 B 3", "B 3 B 4", "B 4 B 4", "C 1 C 1", "C 1 C 2", "C 1 C 3", 
"C 1 C 4", "C 2 C 2", "C 2 C 3", "C 2 C 4", "C 3 C 3", "C 3 C 4", 
"C 4 C 4", "D 1 D 1", "D 1 D 2", "D 1 D 3", "D 1 D 4", "D 2 D 2", 
"D 2 D 3", "D 2 D 4", "D 3 D 3", "D 3 D 4", "D 4 D 4", "E 1 E 1", 
"E 1 E 2", "E 1 E 3", "E 1 E 4", "E 2 E 2", "E 2 E 3", "E 2 E 4", 
"E 3 E 3", "E 3 E 4", "E 4 E 4", "F 1 F 1", "F 1 F 2", "F 1 F 3", 
"F 1 F 4", "F 2 F 2", "F 2 F 3", "F 2 F 4", "F 3 F 3", "F 3 F 4", 
"F 4 F 4", "G 1 G 1", "G 1 G 2", "G 1 G 3", "G 1 G 4", "G 2 G 2", 
"G 2 G 3", "G 2 G 4", "G 3 G 3", "G 3 G 4", "G 4 G 4", "H 1 H 1", 
"H 1 H 2", "H 1 H 3", "H 1 H 4", "H 2 H 2", "H 2 H 3", "H 2 H 4", 
"H 3 H 3", "H 3 H 4", "H 4 H 4", "I 1 I 1", "I 1 I 2", "I 1 I 3", 
"I 1 I 4", "I 2 I 2", "I 2 I 3", "I 2 I 4", "I 3 I 3", "I 3 I 4", 
"I 4 I 4", "J 1 J 1", "J 1 J 2", "J 1 J 3", "J 1 J 4", "J 2 J 2", 
"J 2 J 3", "J 2 J 4", "J 3 J 3", "J 3 J 4", "J 4 J 4"), .Dim = c(10L, 
10L))
```